# Using VBA check a tagged field in adobe PRO

Tags: vba, adobe

I have code that reads 3 records set and inserts information in to adobe PDF file text boxes. but now I want to start checking off adobe check boxes on the form. I have the styles as cross on the boxes and to simple check it off.

Here is my code. It's at the bottom. I am trying to add it.

```
Private Sub Command46_Click()

Dim StrSQl As String
Dim Acrobat As AcroApp
Dim AcrobatDocument  As AcroAVDoc

Dim fcount As Long
Dim AFieldName As String
Dim rsTable As DAO.Recordset
Dim Rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim rs1 As DAO.Recordset
Dim rs2 As DAO.Recordset

Set dbs = CurrentDb
SP = "SP"
y = "Y"

EDIPI = Forms![COLA Form]![EDIPI INPUT].Value

'Query data for MARINES INFO
StrSQl = ""

'Query For depn information other that SP
strSQLDEPN = ""

'Query for spouse information
strSQLSP = "





'Open a dynaset-type Recordset using a SQL
Set Rs = dbs.OpenRecordset(StrSQl, dbOpenDynaset)
Set rs1 = dbs.OpenRecordset(strSQLDEPN, dbOpenDynaset)
Set rs2 = dbs.OpenRecordset(strSQLSP, dbOpenDynaset)

'On Error Resume Next

   depn2a = rs1.Fields("Depn Info First Name").Value + " " + rs1.Fields("Depn Info Mid Initial Id").Value + " " + rs1.Fields("Depn Info Last Name").Value
   reldepn2a = rs1.Fields("Depn Info Relationship Code").Value
   GAINDTD2a = rs1.Fields("Depn Info Birth Date").Value
   rs1.MoveNext

   depn3a = rs1.Fields("Depn Info First Name").Value + " " + rs1.Fields("Depn Info Mid Initial Id").Value + " " + rs1.Fields("Depn Info Last Name").Value
   reldepn3a = rs1.Fields("Depn Info Relationship Code").Value
   GAINDTD3a = rs1.Fields("Depn Info Birth Date").Value
   rs1.MoveNext

   depn4a = rs1.Fields("Depn Info First Name").Value + " " + rs1.Fields("Depn Info Mid Initial Id").Value + " " + rs1.Fields("Depn Info Last Name").Value
   reldepn4a = rs1.Fields("Depn Info Relationship Code").Value
   GAINDTD4a = rs1.Fields("Depn Info Birth Date").Value
   rs1.MoveNext

   depn5a = rs1.Fields("Depn Info First Name").Value + " " + rs1.Fields("Depn Info Mid Initial Id").Value + " " + rs1.Fields("Depn Info Last Name").Value
   reldepn5a = rs1.Fields("Depn Info Relationship Code").Value
   GAINDTD5a = rs1.Fields("Depn Info Birth Date").Value
   rs1.MoveNext

   depn5a = rs1.Fields("Depn Info First Name").Value + " " + rs1.Fields("Depn Info Mid Initial Id").Value + " " + rs1.Fields("Depn Info Last Name").Value
   reldepn5a = rs1.Fields("Depn Info Relationship Code").Value
   GAINDTD5a = rs1.Fields("Depn Info Birth Date").Value
   rs1.MoveNext

   depn6a = rs1.Fields("Depn Info First Name").Value + " " + rs1.Fields("Depn Info Mid Initial Id").Value + " " + rs1.Fields("Depn Info Last Name").Value
   reldepn6a = rs1.Fields("Depn Info Relationship Code").Value
   GAINDTD6a = rs1.Fields("Depn Info Birth Date").Value
   rs1.MoveNext


 If Len(depn2a) = 0 Then
 depn2a = "AND NO OTHERS"
 ElseIf Len(depn3a) = 0 Then
 depn3a = "AND NO OTHERS"
 ElseIf Len(depn4a) = 0 Then
 depn4a = "AND NO OTHERS"
 ElseIf Len(depn5a) = 0 Then
 depn5a = "AND NO OTHERS"
 ElseIf Len(depn6a) = 0 Then
 depn6a = "AND NO OTHERS"

 End If


'WRITING TO A ADOBE PRO FILE.
'On Error GoTo ProcError
Set Acrobat = CreateObject("AcroExch.App")
Set AcrobatDocument = CreateObject("AcroExch.AVDoc")

If AcrobatDocument.Open("C:\Users\jeffrey.spangler\Desktop\4 FORMS.PDF", "") Then

Acrobat.Show

Set AcroForm = CreateObject("AFormAut.App")
Set Fields = AcroForm.Fields 'NUMBER OF FIELDS

     'varibles from form

     'varibles from recordsets

     First = Rs.Fields("First Name").Value
     Last = Rs.Fields("Last Name").Value

     If Not (Rs.Fields("Middle Initial") = Null) Then
     MI = " "
     ElseIf Len(Rs.Fields("Middle Initial")) = 1 Then
     MI = Rs.Fields("Middle Initial")
     End If

     Grade = Rs.Fields("Rank Id").Value
     DOR = Rs.Fields("Permanent Rank Date").Value
     SSN = Rs.Fields("SSN").Value
     DCTB = Rs.Fields("Current Tour Begin Date").Value

     If rs2.RecordCount = 1 Then
     SPOUSENAME = rs2.Fields("Depn Info First Name").Value + " " + Rs.Fields("Depn Info Mid Initial Id").Value + " " + Rs.Fields("Depn Info Last Name").Value
     SpRel = "SPOUSE"
     DOM = rs2.Fields("Depn Info Gain Date").Value
     Else: SPOUSENAME = "N/A"
     End If

     ' Loacting Blanket letters

     'IF than statement to get history statements for commrats approval
     Fields("LNAME").Value = Last
     Fields("FNAME").Value = First
     Fields("MI").Value = MI
     Fields("RANK").Value = Grade
     Fields("DOR").Value = DOR
     Fields("SSN").Value = SSN
     Fields("STATION").Value = "MCB Kaneohe Bay, HI"
     Fields("DATE OF ORDERS").Value = DCTB
     Fields("ARRIVAL").Value = DCTB

     Fields("spouse").Value = SPOUSENAME
     Fields("relationship").Value = SpRel
     Fields("DOM").Value = DOM

     Fields("depn 1").Value = depn2a
     Fields("relation 2").Value = reldepn2a
     Fields("dob1").Value = GAINDTD2a

     Fields("depn 2").Value = depn3a
     Fields("relation 3").Value = reldepn3a
     Fields("dob2").Value = GAINDTD3a

     Fields("depn 3").Value = depn4a
     Fields("relation4").Value = reldepn4a
     Fields("dob3").Value = GAINDTD4a

     Fields("depn4").Value = depn5a
     Fields("relation5").Value = reldepn5a
     Fields("dob4").Value = GAINDTD5a

     Fields("depn5").Value = depn6a
     Fields("relation6").Value = reldepn6a
     Fields("dob5").Value = GAINDTD6a


     Fields("sponsorship").Value = "N/A"
     Fields("Check Box1").Value = "x" '
```

this is my last failed try. here is where the help is needed

```
Else

MsgBox ("failure to locate form")
End If
Acrobat.Exit

Set Acrobat = Nothing
Set AcrobatDocument = Nothing
Set Field = Nothing
Set Fields = Nothing
Rs.Close
Set Rs = Nothing
Set rs1 = Nothing

ProcExit:
  Exit Sub

ProcError:
If Err.Number = 3021 Then
MsgBox Err.Description
End If

 Resume ProcExit



    End Sub
```

the code runs like a champ other that the obvious break.

Comment: You pasted in an enormous amount of code. Not sure, exactly, what you're expecting. Any chance you can edit and reduce what you posted?

Comment: i just figured it out.

Comment: You have to Change the Property settings options change yes to -1 to set up the input.  the input is  Fields("Check Box1").Value = -1

Comment: Ok, great, so post it as a proper answer and not as a comment. That way, you can properly close out this question.

Answer (score 0):

You have to Change the Property settings options change yes to -1 to set up the input. the input is Fields("Check Box1").Value = -1